# Is it possible to setup default value for DateTimeOffset struct?

Tags: c#, .net, datetimeoffset

The situation:
I may have such strings "12/12/2022 10:10:10" or "10:10:10" and i need parse them to DateTimeOffset. If i use TryParse(stringVal, offset), the date for second string will be current day, month and year(as default ones), but i wanna specify my own default value. Is it possible to do so?

If it is not possible, can you, please, suggest ways how to have this custom date in case of time only string, including culture sensitivity? If i have string "current date 12:12:12" it should not be reverted to default, only if "12:12:12".

Comment: If you were using `DateTime.TryParse` instead, you could pass `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault`. Apparently this is not supported by DateTimeOffset and throws an exception, per https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you know the exact formats of the strings you will be parsing you can use `TryParseExact` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0#system-datetimeoffset-tryparseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetimeoffset@) so you can differentiate between a string with a date and one without.

Comment: Format might be any. Any supported by Datetime

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.